# import Json to html (table)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

im trying to import a json url to html in a table. The problem is when i get the data i get 25 rows  i get this on the web console: Object { data: Array[25], paging: Object }  I also have the following code  which is designed for only one row i guess .And i understand i have Loop over each object, appending a table row with the relevant data of each iteration. The problem is i don´t how to do it, i´m not an expert . Thank you for your help!

This is the data i get on the json url :

```
 {
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2017-11-10T01:24:47+0000",
         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1539014319521507",
         "id": "949007375188874_1539014319521507"
      },
      {
         "created_time": "2017-11-10T01:23:37+0000",
         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1539013649521574",
         "id": "949007375188874_1539013649521574"
      },
      {
         "created_time": "2017-11-09T23:59:15+0000",
         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1538951229527816",
         "id": "949007375188874_1538951229527816",
         "shares": {
            "count": 20
         }
      },
      {
         "created_time": "2017-11-09T23:32:30+0000",
         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1538935439529395",
         "id": "949007375188874_1538935439529395"
      },
```

And this my code

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="txtPagina">
    <button class="btnBuscar">Buscar</button>
    <table class="tabla" border='1'>
         <tr>

             <td>created time</td>
             <td>permalink url</td>
             <td>id</td>
             <td>Shares Count</td>


         </tr>
    </table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btnBuscar').on('click', function (){
            var pagina = $('.txtPagina').val();

            //Ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+pagina+"/feed?fields=created_time,permalink_url,id,shares& access_token=mytoken",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                   $('.tabla').append("<tr><td>"+data.created_time+"</td><td>"+data.permalink_url+"</td><td>"+data.id+"</td><td>"+data.shares+"</td></tr>");
                },
                error: function (){
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
  $('.tabla').append("<tr><td>"+data.created_time+"</td><td>"+data.permalink_url+"</td><td>"+data.id+"</td><td>"+data.shares+"</td></tr>");
 },
```

should be

```
success: function(data){
  $.each(data.data, function(i, d){
    var s = d.shares ? '<td>'+d.shares.count+'</td>' : '';
    $('.tabla').append('<tr><td>'+d.created_time+'</td><td>'+d.permalink_url+'</td><td>'+d.id+'</td>'+s+'</tr>');
  });
},
```

Comment: Wait, almost. The table shows the data but the last one Shares count shows  [object Object]  and i should see a number.

Comment: Fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you, now the table shows only one row (With value) and the web console shows this error: TypeError: d.shares is undefined

Comment: It now tests to see d.shares exist.

Comment: Awesome Bro, Thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function create(t,attr,parent_node,innerdata){
                var dom = document.createElement(t)
                for(key in attr){
                        dom.setAttribute(key,attr[key])
                }
                dom.innerHTML = innerdata;
                parent_node.appendChild(dom)
                return dom;
        }
window.onload = function () {
        var d = {
                   "data": [
                      {
                         "created_time": "2017-11-10T01:24:47+0000",
                         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1539014319521507",
                         "id": "949007375188874_1539014319521507"
                      },
                      {
                         "created_time": "2017-11-10T01:23:37+0000",
                         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1539013649521574",
                         "id": "949007375188874_1539013649521574"
                      },
                      {
                         "created_time": "2017-11-09T23:59:15+0000",
                         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1538951229527816",
                         "id": "949007375188874_1538951229527816",
                         "shares": {
                            "count": 20
                         }
                      },
                      {
                         "created_time": "2017-11-09T23:32:30+0000",
                         "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/DBZSFANSOFICIAL2/posts/1538935439529395",
                         "id": "949007375188874_1538935439529395"
                      },
                       
                    ]
                }
 var tb= document.getElementById('inputTable')   
        f = {"created_time":1,"permalink_url":1,"id":1,"shares":1}
        d['data'].forEach(function(val){
                tr_dom = create('tr',{},tb,'')
                Object.keys(f).forEach(function(tr){
                        if(tr in  val){
                                if('shares' == tr)
                                        td_dom = create('td',{},tr_dom,val[tr]['count'])
                                else
                                        td_dom = create('td',{},tr_dom,val[tr])
                        }else
                                td_dom = create('td',{},tr_dom,'')
                })
        })

     };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <table border='1'>
                        <thead>
                                <th>Create Time</th>
                                <th>permalink_url</th>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Share</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="inputTable">
                        </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```